# What does :provided mean in profiles.clj?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, luminus, environ

Luminus right now is creating a profiles.clj with this content:

```
{:provided {:env {;;when set the application start the nREPL server on load
                  :nrepl-port "7001"
                  :database-url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqlkorma_dev?user=db_user_name_here&password=db_user_password_here"}}}
```

What does :provided do here? In environ's documentation it seems to point to having two entries, one for dev and one for test https://github.com/weavejester/environ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The **provided** profile is used in *profiles.clj* as an alternative to the **dev** profile, because if **dev** is used there it would **overwrite the entire *dev* profile** specified in *project.clj*.

---

The most common use of `:provided` is to specify dependencies that should be available during jar creation, but will be provided by the runtime environment. But I think here is used as a way to prevent the `:env` configured in *profiles.clj* (which is intended to not be committed into your source code repository) to overwrite the `:env` configured in *project.clj*.

Luminus would have used the `:dev` profile instead of `:provided` in *profiles.clj*, if it wasn't by the fact that they already put stuff in an `:env` entry in the `:dev` profile in *project.clj* which would be overwritten by what's in *profiles.clj*.

See [this example repo](https://github.com/nberger/tryenv). If you run it right away, without any change (with `:provided` in *profiles.clj*) the output will be:

```
› lein run
Hello, world
Db config: some:db://localhost
```

If you change `:provided` to `:dev` in *profiles.clj*, the output changes to:

```
› lein run
Hello, nil
Db config: some:db://localhost
```

They didn't get merged, but the `:env` in *profiles.clj* overwrote the `:env` in *profile.clj*

---

**EDIT**: I just found out that not only the `:env` entry would be overwritten if `:dev` was used in *profiles.clj*. The entire `:dev` profile would be overwritten. This is explained in the [profiles documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#merging):

> Remember that if a profile with the same name is specified in multiple
>   locations, only the profile with the highest "priority" is picked – no
>   merging is done. The "priority" is – from highest to lowest –
>   profiles.clj, project.clj, user-wide profiles, and finally system-wide
>   profiles.

So using `:provided` in *profiles.clj* is a little *hack* around the merging strategy of leiningen profiles.

It has at least one downside: if you need to define a `:provided` profile in *project.clj* to specify dependencies that will be available in the runtime environment it would be overwritten by the one defined in *profiles.clj*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! In Luminus we ended up using a different hack so out of the box it has easy to modify hashmaps for both dev and test in both, project.clj and profiles.clj.

Comment: Cool! Yes, you end up doing different hacks to be able to get to the promise of lein-environ of envs configurable in profiles.clj. I ended up not using lein-environ at all (but keep using environ). environ's README suggests to use :dev and :test in profiles.clj without explaining it would overwrite the same profiles in project.clj. Someone should edit that README explaining this little detail :)

Comment: By the way, there's already an issue about this in environ with a bit of useful info: https://github.com/weavejester/environ/issues/15. The solution I like the most is to redefine the dev profile as `:dev  [:project/dev  :profiles/dev]`

Answer (score 3):

> The **`:provided`** profile is used to specify dependencies that should be available during jar creation, but not propagated to other code that depends on your project. These are dependencies that the project assumes will be provided by whatever environment the jar is used in, but are needed during the development of the project. This is often used for frameworks like Hadoop that provide their own copies of certain libraries.

-- [Reference](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md)

Comment: `:provided` is not being used here for dependencies, but to prevent the `:env` configured in _profiles.clj_ to overwrite the `:env` configured in _project.clj_ and get them merged instead

Comment: It contains a map of profile-specific project properties, basically. It's a common use case to specify a value at `:dependencies` to, well, add `jar`-specific dependencies. But inclusion of other keys is possible too.

Comment: Sure. But the subtlety here is that luminus would have used the `:dev` profile in _profiles.clj_ but is using `:provided` instead. If you create a new luminus project with mysql for example, you will get `{:dev :env {:dev        true :nrepl-port 7001}}` in _project.clj_ and `{:provided {:env {:database-url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trylum_dev?user=db_user_name_here&password=db_user_password_here"}}}` in _profiles.clj_. The strange thing here is why it's not using `:dev` in _profiles.clj_ and I think my answer addresses that.

Comment: @nberger interesting. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As @nberger said `provided` is used to specify dependencies that should be available in your classpath, but will be provided by the runtime.

One particular case is libraries that if included in your project would get their signature messed up when creating the uberjar.

Such is the situation of [BouncyCastle](http://wiki.nikhef.nl/grid/JGridstart/Bouncycastle_and_Java_Web_start).

So your `project.clj` may look like:

```
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on "1.50"]]}
           :provided {:dependencies [[org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on "1.50"]]}}
```

In this situation you say that for development you can use the library from maven repository, but on runtime it must be provided by the environment.

So the original jar file *as-is*, must be present in the classpath:

```
java -cp bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar:your-standalone.jar clojure.main
```